# Angular with Bootstrap NavBar with Dropdown

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I am trying to set the default NavBar bootstrap directly given in the examples of Bootstrap nav bar documentation.

But it looks like not working. The UI is coming properly but dropdown is not working.

Please check below stackblitz link for the same.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sh1tpx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Tried to use the default nav bar example from below link.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.component.html`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      ...
      (click)="toggleNavbarCollapsing()" // <-- add this line
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse" // <-- remove `collapse` class from here
      id="navbarNavDropdown"  
      [class.collapse]="navbarCollapsed"> // <-- add this line
      ...
</nav>
```

and in your `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  
  // add belove code
  navbarCollapsed = true;

  toggleNavbarCollapsing() {
    this.navbarCollapsed = !this.navbarCollapsed;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like bootstrap internally uses Jquery to handle certain operations. And that is causing issues that I faced.